# How to make a Video "mini/filter-driver"

Tags: windows, video, driver

I need to create an application/driver in Windows that captures the video stream from a webcam, performs some modifications and passes it back on to the system (so it streams out to say skype).

Anyone knows how to create / register such an app ? Maybe samples on the web ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454(VS.85).aspx). You need to create a source filter (which gets data from the camera source filter and modifies it).